# update sql foreign key automatically php

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I am having trouble to let foreign key updating itself, the constraint was set as on update cascade on delete cascade in phpmyadmin.
I am able to insert everything else, just the foreign key user_id appearing as null rather than updating to the correct id.
Where was my mistake? id the the table id, I know I don't need to put into the sql statement; user_id is the foreign key linked with tbl_user

**Insert to database codes**

```
try
    {
      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

      $stmt =$dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO tbl_details (user_id, name,address,postcode)
              VALUES(:user_id,:name,:address,:postcode)");



      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id',$user_id);
      $stmt->bindparam(':name', $name);
      ........
      $stmt->execute(); 

      $dbh = null;
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
            $dbh = null;
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            print "PHP Line Number: " . $e->getLine() . "<br/>"; 
            print "PHP File: " . $e->getFile() . "<br/>";
            die();
      }
```

Comment: Where is `$user_id` set?

Comment: tbl_details user_id is the foreign key of tbl_users user_id

Comment: How are you setting the PHP variable `$user_id`?

Comment: I understand `user_id`, but I asked about the php variable `$user_id` that you are using in `$stmt->bindParam(':user_id',$user_id);`. If you don't define `$user_id` in php, then it is `NULL` which is why it is inserted as `NULL`

Comment: @Sean Thank you for your help, sorry I have very little experience in this . I did not set it anywhere that's why then. All I did for setting variable was   if(isset($_POST['btn']) ){    
    $name = $_POST['name']; ...} but not for user_id.   Because I thought I do not need to physically insert the user_id from a form input and then when I try to display the data just used joined table sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its working now, I am missing this

```
$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_details WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
```

Thank you @sean and @Darwin von Corax